# Is it possible to send an email from Excel VBA on a Mac?

Tags: excel, vba, macos, outlook

I have an Excel application that uses:

```
CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

to send an email.

It works fine on a Windows machine but the Outlook library is not available on a Mac (AFAIK).

Is there a way to get this working on a Mac?

Comment: https://www.macexcel.com/examples/mailpdf/macmail/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between Windows and Mac machine. There is no COM technology available on Mac OS. Instead, AppleScript is used instead for automating Office applications. See [Send Mail from Mac Excel with Mac Outlook](https://macexcel.com/examples/mailpdf/macoutlook/) for more information.

Also you may consider sending emails from Excel via Mail, see [Sending email via Mail from Excel Mac automatically](https://medium.com/@cognaticslab/sending-email-via-mail-from-excel-mac-automatically-b726d727816).

Comment: Thanks - both good options. Much appreciated.